# Extract strings that start with ${ and end with }

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the strings from a file that start with `${` and ends with `}` using Python. I am using the code below to do so, but I don't get the expected result.

My input file looks like this:

```
Click    ${SWIFT_TAB}
Click    ${SEARCH_SWIFT_CODE}
```

and I want to get a list as below:

```
${SWIFT_TAB}
${SEARCH_SWIFT_CODE}
```

My current code looks like this:

```
def findStringFromFile(file):
    import os,re    
    with open(file) as f:
        ans = [] 
        for line in f:

            matches = re.findall(r'\b\${\S+}\b', line)
            ans.extend(matches)        
    print (ans)
```

I am expecting a list of strings that start with `${` and end with `}`, but all I currently get is an empty list.

Comment: What exactly does _"it doesn't work"_ mean?

Comment: Why are you creating `start` and `end` and then not using them for anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry , That was some mistake while copying the code.. I have corrected the code that i have used

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: I am expecting a list of string in ans that should contains strings that starts with ${ and ends with }, but i dont get the expected result , if someone could post the code for it

Comment: @Peter Wood I ran it and i didn't get the expected result

Comment: Saying " it doesn't work" and "i dont get the expected result" doesn't tell us much. You need to explain or show us what it prints, and / or any error messages.

Comment: The problem here are the `\b` anchors; they prevent the regex from matching when the curly brace is followed by a special character - like a newline.

Comment: I tried the code 'matches = re.findall(r'\$\{.*\}', line)' , it gave some results. when i verified i could see that it has picked the neighbouring string that in the format &{dic}[temp] and printed it as &{dic} along with my expected result.

Comment: matches = re.findall(r'\$\{(.*)\}', s)  print (matches),.. This will give you the right answer.

Comment: Questions starting with "Please provide the code" are likely to get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your regexp is buggy, and doesn't match the strings you want to extract.  Specifically, you have two issues:

1. `{` and `}` are regexp metacharacters, just like `$`, and also need to be escaped if you want to match them literally.
2. `\b` matches a word boundary, i.e. a position between a "word character" (a letter, a number or an underscore) and a "non-word character" (anything else) or the beginning/end end of string.  It does not match between, say, a space and `$`.

To fix these issues, change your line:

```
matches = re.findall(r'\b\${\S+}\b', line)
```

to:

```
matches = re.findall(r'\$\{\S+\}', line)
```

and it should work.

See the [Python regular expressions documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more details.